# return an array from subscripting operator overload

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, operator-keyword, subscript

I'm getting started with c++ and I have this method where I overload the subscript operator "[ ]" but I need to return an array from that method, In the method, I'm trying to return a sub array from a bigger array but I can't seem to return a whole array since I can only return a single element from an array, how can I get the method to return an entire array?

For example:

```
int& PagedArray::operator [] (int position){
    if(position == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            pageArray[i] = completeArray[i];
            //cout << to_string(i) + " " + to_string(pageArray[i]) << endl;
        }
        return pageArray[0] ;
    }
}
```

When I try to return I can only get a specific element from the array pageArray, but I need to return pageArray, how can I get that done?

thanks

Comment: Switch from using C-style arrays to [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  A `std::vector` can be returned by value.

Comment: @PaulSanders Or by `const&` which is probably what you want here.

Comment: Unrelated: what gets returned when `position != 0`?

Comment: @ChrisMM that's supposed to show in the terminal the message "index out bounds" but clearly the code is not finished yet I was just trying to solve that error first so I can keep going with the rest

Comment: If an array has a fixed length at compile time, it is possible to return a reference to it, and then use `[]` syntax to access its elements (assuming the array exists as long as the reference to it).   If length is not known (e.g. a dynamically allocated array with length determined at run time) it is necessary to return a proxy (e.g. a reference to an object that contains/managers the array and supplies an `operator[]()` that provides access to elements.    Using `std::vector` is (among other things) an example of the second approach

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Yes, possibly.  There's not enough context in the question to know which is more appropriate.

Comment: "I need to return pageArray, how can I get that done?" Simple: `return pageArray`.

Comment: If it's a standard fixed size array (like in C) you can just return a pointer `return pageArray;` and the declaration would be: `int* PagedArray::operator [] (int position)` and bracket index off that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to return an array from that method
>
> ```
> int& PagedArray::operator [] (int position)
> ```

The return type that you've given for your function does not match what you need to return. This function returns a reference to an integer; not an array.

A problem with what you need is that you cannot return an array in C++; that's just not allowed in the language. That is to say, return type cannot be an array. There's a fairly easy way to get around that however: You can return instances of classes and you can store arrays as member of a class. There is a template for such array wrapper class in the standard library. It's called `std::array`.

Here is an example of returning a sub-array:

```
constexpr std::size_t page_size = 256;

std::array<int, page_size>
PagedArray::operator[] (int){
    std::array<int, page_size> page;
    std::copy(completeArray, page);
    return page;
}
```

---

Given that you originally tried to return a reference, you may be looking for a way to avoid copying the sub-array by using indirection.  A problem is that the sub array doesn't exist anywhere prior to calling the function and you cannot return a reference to something that you create in the function.

Instead of returning reference to small array, you can return a subrange pointing to the big array.  There are actually more than one option in the standard library. There's a general purpose `std::ranges::subrange` and also `std::span` that is specific to contiguous ranges. I recommend using the more specific type assuming you aren't templetising the type of the big container. Example:

```
std::span<int, page_size>
PagedArray::operator[] (int){
    return {completeArray, page_size};
}
```